# How to do an automated UI test on a diagramming WPF application

Tags: wpf, testing, automated-tests, appium

Assume i have a WPF diagramming application like this example: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4

- How can I do an automated UI test for functions like:
- Inserting a new item per drag and drop
- Connecting 2 items
- Deleting an item

I seen test libraries like "White" or "Appium" which is good for some text input but I have no glue how to do for example drag and drop of items in an automated test.

Comment: [Does Coded UI Code First API support drag and drop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816139/does-coded-ui-code-first-api-support-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 0):

One diagram application is not like another diagram application. Even if WPF is used in both cases. What counts is the modeling of the items and connecting lines.

If the items are regular WPF controls then any test tool supporting replay (and maybe even recording) of actions like click, mouse press, release and drag will support automation of above actions. With statements like

```
dragAndDrop(source, sx, sy, target, tx, ty)
```

This assumes a reliable *identification* of the source and target objects. Do they have unique properties that tell one e.g. line element from the other?

If the Application Under Test renders the items on a canvas (like WPF Diagram Designer seems to do) then object-based access may be out of question. An image-based approach can be the only viable solution then. An equivalent of above `dragAndDrop()` call using an [image-based](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/features/image-based-testing-tools/) testing:

```
var img = waitForImage("MyItem");
var x = img.x;
var y = img.y;
mousePress(x, y, MouseButton.LeftButton);
mouseMove(x, y);
mouseRelease(x,y, MouseButton.LeftButton);
```

Again, identification of primitive elements like lines can be challenging. In that case I would go for some scripting and query the application's internal model of the diagram structure and position of its elements.